# How to fill array inm loop JS?

Tags: javascript

I have the following array:

```
 var pageviews = [
     [1, randValue()],
     [2, randValue()],
     [3, randValue()],
];
```

This array is filled staticly. How can I fill this in loop?

I tried:

```
 $.each(data, function(k, v) {
      pageviews.push([num, v["value"]]);

})
```

But it gives me different result

Comment: What is `data`? What is `num`? Is `v` an object that has a `value` property?

Comment: `data.map((v,i)=>[i+1, v])`. Also it gives error because `num`  is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
var data = {a:"Hii", b:"bbye"}, // dummy data
pageViews = [];

$.each(data, function(key,val){
  var temp = [];
  temp.push(key,val)
  pageViews.push(temp);
});

//output, pageViews = [["a","Hii"],["b","bbye"]]
```

if you want an index number so define a separate counter variable as:

```
var data = {a:"Hii", b:"bbye"}, // dummy data
pageViews = [],
counter = 1;

$.each(data, function(key,val){
  var temp = [];
  temp.push(counter++,val)
  pageViews.push(temp);
});

//output, pageViews = [[1,"Hii"],[2,"bbye"]]
```